# Match All CSS Files in Wordpress HTML

Tags: php, css, regex, wordpress, preg-match-all

I am attempting to capture all CSS files in the HTML generated from a Wordpress site.

So far I have the following

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+?\.css)"/', $op, $css);
```

This gets me all *.css URL's that have no querystring, but as I am sure you are aware, WP has a funny way of appending a querystring to them... so the 20+ rest of the CSS files are not captured.

How can I mod this to grab them all?

Dom parsing is not an option as WP very rarely produces valid html...

Comment: I'm not aware of the context, e.g.: what's in $op and $css. But my first try would be `preg_match_all('/"([^"]+?\.css.+(?<!"))"/', $op, $css);`

Comment: I guess you could do a `"([^"]+?\.css[^."]*)"` which might get with/without.

Comment: Neither of these do it.  Context?  Wordpress generated HTML as stated in the question...

Comment: @Kevin - Really? My regex didn't match? Show a sample string you need to match then. As far as I recall `[^"]*"` will match '.css`anything you find here except double quote"`'

Comment: I'm not going to post the full HTML that $op ='s    Any wordpress site would probably do the trick LOL   I wonder if it's that last `"` doing it

Comment: Here's an example of what yours is doing: http://kevinpirnie.com/default.php  and all I am doing to get the content is a simple curl request to string output for the full HTML (yes verified)

Comment: read this! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748052/getting-a-all-css-files-of-an-html-web-page

Comment: Dom parsing is **not** an option due to the p.poor way wordpress presents it's html for about 80% of the wordpress sites out there.

Comment: Believe you me @NelsonGuamanLeiva I wish I could do it like that...  unfortunately, as I'm sure you're aware... wp's not the friendliest of beasts to developers :D lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If DOM parsing is not an option, consider the following code. You were close:

```
// just a random css link
$str = "href='/wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css?ver=2.3.4.3'";

// match href literally, then use a named group called css
$regex = "/href=['\"](?P<css>([^'\"]+?\.css)[^'\"]*)/";
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches["css"]);
// e.g. /wp-content/themes/optimizePressTheme/lib/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css?ver=2.3.4.3
```

Please consider nevertheless using a DOM Parser, it will mostly work [with badly formatted HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351526/parsing-of-badly-formated-html-in-php) as well.

Comment: Dang close ;)  Thanks.  Check out items 6 & 7 tho: http://kevinpirnie.com/default.php?_=6

Comment: Will look into it more closely tomorrow. Is your link still valid then?

Comment: Take your time mate, yeah it should be

Comment: @Kevin: I forgot a single quote in the brackets, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hey @Jan  still no go: http://kevinpirnie.com/default.php?_=6    missing the ones in the bottom box

Comment: @Kevin Changed the last `+` to a star (`*`), see my updated answer. Assuming, this comes all from your website, I do match 30 css files now including the ones with js_composer. This matches for css files without the query string appended as well (`*` means zero times or more).

Comment: bingo!    Thanks Jan, now onto bigger better(hopefully) things ;)